# Самая современная реализация слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, слайдер

Необходимо реализовать слайдер вручную (без использования swiper и т. п.). Подскажите **наиболее современные** способы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Недавно писал свой слайдер по этому примеру:
https://medium.com/@claudiaconceic/infinite-plain-javascript-slider-click-and-touch-events-540c8bd174f2

В этом примере реализуется бесконечный слайдер, далее можно уже расширять функционал по желанию.

Суть следующая:
Создаем блок нашего слайдера с `overflow: hidden` и внутри него помещаем блок ленты, которая содержит слайды, чтобы получилось следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, для реализации эффекта бесконечности, нужно клонировать необходимое количество слайдов в начале и конце нашей ленты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Анимацию переключения слайдов реализуем с помощью свойства left нашей ленты. После каждого переключения проверяем, находимся ли мы в начале или в конце ленты, если так, то отключаем transition и меняем left с дублирующего слайда на позицию оригинального. Так и создается эффект бесконечности.

Продублирую код примера из оригинальной статьи:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider'),
  sliderItems = document.getElementById('slides'),
  prev = document.getElementById('prev'),
  next = document.getElementById('next');

function slide(wrapper, items, prev, next) {
  var posX1 = 0,
    posX2 = 0,
    posInitial,
    posFinal,
    threshold = 100,
    slides = items.getElementsByClassName('slide'),
    slidesLength = slides.length,
    slideSize = items.getElementsByClassName('slide')[0].offsetWidth,
    firstSlide = slides[0],
    lastSlide = slides[slidesLength - 1],
    cloneFirst = firstSlide.cloneNode(true),
    cloneLast = lastSlide.cloneNode(true),
    index = 0,
    allowShift = true;

  // Clone first and last slide
  items.appendChild(cloneFirst);
  items.insertBefore(cloneLast, firstSlide);
  wrapper.classList.add('loaded');

  // Mouse events
  items.onmousedown = dragStart;

  // Touch events
  items.addEventListener('touchstart', dragStart);
  items.addEventListener('touchend', dragEnd);
  items.addEventListener('touchmove', dragAction);

  // Click events
  prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
    shiftSlide(-1)
  });
  next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    shiftSlide(1)
  });

  // Transition events
  items.addEventListener('transitionend', checkIndex);

  function dragStart(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    posInitial = items.offsetLeft;

    if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
      posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
    } else {
      posX1 = e.clientX;
      document.onmouseup = dragEnd;
      document.onmousemove = dragAction;
    }
  }

  function dragAction(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.type == 'touchmove') {
      posX2 = posX1 - e.touches[0].clientX;
      posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
    } else {
      posX2 = posX1 - e.clientX;
      posX1 = e.clientX;
    }
    items.style.left = (items.offsetLeft - posX2) + "px";
  }

  function dragEnd(e) {
    posFinal = items.offsetLeft;
    if (posFinal - posInitial < -threshold) {
      shiftSlide(1, 'drag');
    } else if (posFinal - posInitial > threshold) {
      shiftSlide(-1, 'drag');
    } else {
      items.style.left = (posInitial) + "px";
    }

    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }

  function shiftSlide(dir, action) {
    items.classList.add('shifting');

    if (allowShift) {
      if (!action) {
        posInitial = items.offsetLeft;
      }

      if (dir == 1) {
        items.style.left = (posInitial - slideSize) + "px";
        index++;
      } else if (dir == -1) {
        items.style.left = (posInitial + slideSize) + "px";
        index--;
      }
    };

    allowShift = false;
  }

  function checkIndex() {
    items.classList.remove('shifting');

    if (index == -1) {
      items.style.left = -(slidesLength * slideSize) + "px";
      index = slidesLength - 1;
    }

    if (index == slidesLength) {
      items.style.left = -(1 * slideSize) + "px";
      index = 0;
    }

    allowShift = true;
  }
}

slide(slider, sliderItems, prev, next);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #7656d6;
  color: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: -400px;
  width: 10000px;
}

.slides.shifting {
  transition: left .2s ease-out;
}

.slide {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFCF47;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.slider.loaded .slide:nth-child(2),
.slide:nth-child(7) {
  background: #FFCF47
}

.slider.loaded .slide:nth-child(1),
.slider.loaded .slide:nth-child(6) {
  background: #7ADCEF
}

.slider.loaded .slide:nth-child(3) {
  background: #3CFF96
}

.slider.loaded .slide:nth-child(4) {
  background: #a78df5
}

.slider.loaded .slide:nth-child(5) {
  background: #ff8686
}

.control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 2;
}

.prev,
.next {
  background-size: 22px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/navigation-set-arrows-part-one/32/ChevronLeft-512.png);
  left: -20px;
}

.next {
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/navigation-set-arrows-part-one/32/ChevronRight-512.png);
  right: -20px;
}

.prev:active,
.next:active {
  transform: scale(.8);
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="slider">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="slides" class="slides">
      <span class="slide">Slide 1</span>
      <span class="slide">Slide 2</span>
      <span class="slide">Slide 3</span>
      <span class="slide">Slide 4</span>
      <span class="slide">Slide 5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="prev" class="control prev"></a>
  <a id="next" class="control next"></a>
</div>
```

Думаю это вполне современный способ реализации слайдера.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/764192)

Comment: @Vanyamba Electronics , исправил. Добавил суть и приложил код из оригинальной статьи. Так правильно?

Comment: Прекрасный ответ.